# Testing a .NET 7 isolated worker azure function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-functions

I have created a .NET 7 isolated worker function that includes some middleware. Now, I'm looking to self-host this function to enable the creation of a test that checks whether both the function and its associated middleware perform as intended (by running the function and its corresponding middleware in a single test). Does anyone have guidance on accomplishing this?

```
internal sealed class StampHttpHeaderMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly ***create one XUnit or any Testing Project inside your existing Function solution*** and add the below code:-

My **Function Solution with Test Project**:-

***Code1:-***

My UnitTests.cs:-

```cs
using System.Net;
using FunctionApp63;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace FunctionApp63.Tests
{
    public class Function1Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Run_Returns_Welcome_Message()
        {
            // Arrange
            var loggerFactoryMock = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();

            loggerFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(loggerMock.Object);

            var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestData>();
            var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseData>();

            // Simulate the function call
            var function = new Function1(loggerFactoryMock.Object);
            var response = function.Run(requestMock.Object);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(response);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

            // Verify that the response contains the expected content type
            Assert.True(response.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Type", out var contentTypes));
            Assert.Contains("text/plain; charset=utf-8", contentTypes);
        }
    }
}
```

*Output:-**

[image]

***Code2:-***

My UnitTests.cs:-

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace FunctionApp63.Tests
{
    public class Function1IntegrationTests
    {
        private const string FunctionBaseUrl = "http://localhost:7083"; // Replace with your function host URL

        [Fact]
        public async Task Run_Returns_Welcome_Message()
        {
            // Arrange
            using var client = new HttpClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri($"{FunctionBaseUrl}/api/Function1"));

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(response);
            Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.Contains("Welcome to Azure Functions!", content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***With Middleware:-***

I have implemented a **custom middleware** with my .Net 7.0 Isolated Http Trigger and Performed Test for both like below:-

Created a Folder named **Middleware** and Added **LoggingMiddleware.cs** inside it like below:-

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;

namespace FunctionApp62
{
    public class LoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware

    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public LoggingMiddleware(ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Middleware executing before function.");

            await next(context);

            _logger.LogInformation("Middleware executing after function.");
        }
    }
}
```

Create one Test folder and Added ***Function1Tests.cs*** File with the code below:-

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace FunctionApp62.Tests
{
    public class Function1Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public Task TestFunction()
        {
            var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
            var loggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
            loggerFactory.Setup(factory => factory.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(logger.Object);

            var httpRequestData = new Mock<HttpRequestData>();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

My Program.cs including the middleware:-

```cs
using FunctionApp62;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSingleton<LoggingMiddleware>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

My ***Function1.cs with the middleware***:-

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace FunctionApp62
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly LoggingMiddleware _loggingMiddleware;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, LoggingMiddleware loggingMiddleware)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
            _loggingMiddleware = loggingMiddleware;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add Xunit inside this Function Solution with middleware and perform the tests:-

**My Solution:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azure-functions-tests/csharp-visualstudio at master · Azure-Samples/azure-functions-tests (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-functions-tests/tree/master/csharp-visualstudio)

Comment: The azure-functions-tests are for `HttpRequest` and not `HttpRequestData`, how is it relevant? Its last commit was in 2018. Am i missing something?

Comment: When I wrote same integration testing I got: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.